# Android Studio - Items on Emulator Not Showing up

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, mobile

I'm currently stuck trying to figure out why my RecycleView and Add button isn't showing up on my emulator when I run it, yet it shows up on the preview panel of my IDE. I have tried turning on the System UI and working around that, but it doesn't show up when I do that either. What could be causing that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="681dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:text="Add" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="683dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/add_an_item_here" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etItem"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Emulator]

[image: IDE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try exactly this one in the xml layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Add" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="THIS IS HINT" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etItem"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It worked thanks for the help! Do you know why my code may have had the button and recycleview disappear on the emulator? I'm still stumped on what may have caused that.

Comment: You use to many unnecessary properties. I guess in your case, set marginTop to 681dp push the button out of the screen since the height of your screen is less than 681dp. You can try to change the margin value to 2000dp to see the change in preview window. If you find my answer is helpful, please don't forget to give it a checkmark.

Comment: It looked like marginTop was the problem. Gave you a checkmark thanks for the help again.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "android:layout_marginTop" and "android:layout_alignParentTop" properties from Button or EditText.
Please check below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
android:text="Add" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/etItem"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnAdd"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnAdd"
android:autofillHints=""
android:ems="10"
android:hint="Enter value" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/etItem"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
android:text="Add" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/etItem"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnAdd"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnAdd"
android:autofillHints=""
android:ems="10"
android:hint="Enter value" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/etItem"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I upvoted your comment! It did end out being the marginTop and alignParentTop